# Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version

Tags: java, android-ndk

what can i do my Android studio show this Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version Unknown.So What Cane I do Sir Please Help me.......
I just installed the newest of Android Studio, and I opened my project and started to sync and this error showed up: NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to me.
It is solved almost by magic.

In the files build.gradle, comment the dependencies:

```
 dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    ...
    }
```

"Comemnt with block Comment" and "Sync Now".

And then, I replaced the dependencies.